# Django - Run all tests inside of "test" sub-folder

Tags: python, django

So I've been running tests using the command `python manage.py test` to run every test inside the `test` folder and I'd like to run all test in a subfolder of the `test` folder. So I tried `python manage.py test <app name>.test.<sub-folder>`(path to the test sub-folder), but it doesn't work. I created an `__init__.py` file inside `<sub-folder>` that imports all the test files in `<sub-folder>`, but that didn't work. Every time I run `python manage.py test <app name>.test.<sub-folder>` the terminal outputs `Run 0 tests in <X number of seconds>s`.

For example, typically in Django there's a root project folder then a `test` folder inside of that and then you can put folders with different test files in each folder. So I want to be able to run something like all the tests in folder `project_folder/test/test_folder_A`.

**How do you run all tests inside of a sub-folder of the test folder in Django?**

Comment: Just curious, wouldn't the command `python manage.py test` run all those tests that reside in `<app_name>/tests/*` ?

Comment: @JPG my folder name is name singular as in `test` not `tests`. Yes it runs all test in `<app_name>/test/`

Answer (score 1):

You may have reviewed it already, but the Django unit testing documentation provides some helpful information on how to run unit tests in a single package and/or module.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/testing/overview/#running-tests

Based on your problem description, it sounds like you tried to create a package for your sub-folder and run the `test` command using that package path. If you tried creating a package and running the `test` command with that package path, but no tests were run, then my first thought is that it might be an issue with the package path that was supplied to the `test` command.

To resolve this issue, it might be helpful to first try and run the unit tests in a single python file/module. This can be done by passing the module name/path to the `test` command. Once you are able to get that working, then you could take the next step and try doing the same for an entire unit test folder/package.

**EDIT**: I was able to create a simple Django app and run only the unit tests in a specific sub-folder/package. My sample application code, along with brief repro steps, may be found on my GitHub page at the following link:

https://github.com/frederickm13/code-samples/tree/master/Django/unit-testing-django

Please review and compare what may be different between your project's structure and the structure of my sample application.

A few main points that I would like to note:

- In order for the default Python `unittest` test runner to discover test files, the files must match the `test*.py` naming convention.
- In order to run only the tests in a specific sub-folder/package, all folders in the Python package path must have an `__init__.py` file created within them. This signifies that those folders are Python packages. The full Python package path must then be passed to the test command as follows:

`./manage.py test <parent_package>.<sub_package>.<sub_sub_package>`

Comment: yep I'm able to fun a single file/module. I'll take a look at the docs. Running a folder of tests should run using the command I listed in the original post yes?

Comment: @user8714896 - You are correct. I believe that I was able to achieve the intended result using a simple Django application that I created. Please see my edits in my answer above, along with a link to my GitHub repository where the sample code is stored.